# Branching Arrows 1-to-2 using Tikz?

Tags: tikz-arrows

I can't find the stackexchange answer currently, but I previously copied some code that allowed me to have an arrow branch one equation to two, like the following:

[image]

Which can be reproduced with the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzsymbols}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{subequations}
\label{eq1}
\noindent
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=-.4cm and 1.5cm]
\node (A) 
    {$  \overset{t_{B}}{\text{A}} $};
\node[above right=of A] (B) 
    {$ \overset{t_{B}}{\text{B}} $
    };
\node[below right=of A] (C)    
    {$ \overset{t_{C}}{\text{C}}$}; 
    \draw[-stealth, line width=1mm] (A.0) -- ( $ (A.0)!0.15!(B.west|-A.0) $ ) |- (B.west) node[auto,pos=0.75] {\scalebox{1}{$h$}};
    \draw[-stealth, line width=1mm] (A.0) -- ( $ (A.0)!0.15!(C.west|-A.0) $ ) |- (C.west) node[auto,pos=0.75] {\scalebox{1}{$g$}} ; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{subequations}



\end{document}
```

But as you can see from the picture, the overset of the equations appears to shift the equations line down relative to the arrow center. I would like the arrows to be pointing to the middle of the equations, and currently it appears to be offset. (In this minimalist example it doesn't look so bad, but if these branches are longer equations, it's clear that this is very offset and looks very off.)

Because this code is really a hack of some copy+pasted code, I don't really understand what has been done well enough to modify it for my use case (of shifting the nodes down slightly).

Any ideas what can be done?

Comment: Please provide a minimum worked full code of your problem. Using the piece of code you offered others can not reproduce your document.

Comment: I corrected that now, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

The reason of offset is you using `\overset` in your equations. Without the `\overset` the arrows will be pointing to the center of the equations. There is a solution:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzsymbols}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{subequations}
\label{eq1}
\noindent
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=-.4cm and 1.5cm]
\node (A) 
    {$  \overset{t_{B}}{\text{A}}-M\cdot C^2 $};
\node[above right=of A] (B) 
    {$ \overset{t_{B}}{\text{B}}-M\cdot C^2 $
    };
\node[below right=of A] (C)    
    {$ \overset{t_{C}}{\text{C}}-M\cdot C^2$}; 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% shift down the arrows pointing location %
% by 3.5pt                                %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\coordinate (AR) at ($(A.east)-(0pt,3.5pt)$);
\coordinate (BL) at ($(B.west)-(0pt,3.5pt)$);
\coordinate (CL) at ($(C.west)-(0pt,3.5pt)$);
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\draw[-stealth, line width=1mm] (AR) -- ( $ (AR)!0.15!(BL|-AR) $ ) |- (BL) node[auto,pos=0.75] {\scalebox{1}{$h$}};
\draw[-stealth, line width=1mm] (AR) -- ( $ (AR)!0.15!(CL|-AR) $ ) |- (CL) node[auto,pos=0.75] {\scalebox{1}{$g$}} ; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{subequations}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for this!